# Rails with searching dependent value in create a new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, search, filter, find

Recently started to study rails and faced with the next problem:

I have two tables Inboxes(request) and Equipments. Inboxes has many Equipments through InboxEquipment.

Since the equipment can be many, the searching for the right is difficult. I need to add field quick **search** or **filter** values of table Equipments. I think this can be done using Ajax, but I don't know him. Something similar is described in "Episode #240 Search, Sort, Paginate with AJAX", but I don't know how to make to search has been in the create a new record

*My current working code:*

**../controllers/inbox_controller.rb**

```
def new
    if signed_in?
        @inbox = Inbox.new(params[:inbox])
        @partners = @inbox.partners.build(params[:partners])
        @equipments = @inbox.equipments.search(params[:search])
    end
end
```

**../inboxes/new.html.erb**

```
<% if signed_in? %>
<%= render 'shared/inbox_form' %>
<% end %>
```

**../shared/_inbox_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @inbox, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <div class="new_application">

        <h2>Входящая заявка</h2>

        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <div class="fields_inbox">
            <h4><center>Контрагент:</center></h4>
            <%= f.select(:partner_id, options_for_select(Partner.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, :include_blank => "Выберите контрагента")) %>

            <%= f.select(:equipment_ids, options_for_select(Equipment.all.collect { |z| [z.name, z.id] }), {}, {:multiple=>true, :size => 10}) %>

            <h4><center>Тип заявки:</center></h4>
            <%=  f.select(:application_type, ["Новая","Принята","На рассмотрении","Завершена"], :include_blank => "Выберите тип зявки") %>
            <center>
                <%= f.submit "Добавить", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
                <%= link_to "Назад", :back, :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>    
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

Add two images as works now and how to

So now working http://s12.postimg.org/vt91ceqkd/inbox.jpg 
So it should work http://s22.postimg.org/z20zb8c9d/inbox_correct.jpg

What do I need to add to my code to make it work as I need to (Example in second image)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get your question... Could you be a little more specific? What is going wrong/what error message do you get?

Comment: Sorry, my English may be wrong... There are no errors. I need to add one text field between <%= f.select(:partner_id,... %> and <%= f.select(:equipment_ids,... %> by which to filter equipments in 
<%= f.select(:equipment_ids, options_for_select(Equipment.all.collect { |z| [z.name, z.id] }), {}, {:multiple=>true, :size => 10}) %>

Comment: To make it more clear added two images: so now working http://s12.postimg.org/vt91ceqkd/inbox.jpg, so it should work http://s22.postimg.org/z20zb8c9d/inbox_correct.jpg